# Mass Email to Campaign Members, what's the limit?

Tags: email, massemailmessage, email-alert

I'd like to send a emails to a large number of account and contacts when they are campaign members.

I know it is possible to do this via the standard sfdc interface, but it is unclear how many emails can be sent per day like this. I've read that the limit is 1000 "external addresses", does it apply here too? Must the emails be divided in batches (I've read that one must select 500 campagin members at a time)?

Also, if I want to use APEX and use the method: setTargetObjectIds, will this also count toward the 1000 email per fay limits?

Thank you very much for your assistance,
T.

Comment: As per my experiments setTargetObjectIds method count towards email limit .

Comment: thanks, so the unlimited emails are only for sfdc users (or portal users)?

Answer (score -2):

Good question asked.  I would like to focus light on Salesforce limitations here. 
Edition Address Limit per Mass Email
Professional 250
Enterprise Edition 500
Unlimited Edition 1,000

In order to make yourself Unlimited while sending the mass emails to Contacts, Leads, sending emails to Campaign Members then you need to check an appexchange native app - Massmailer.This will let you bypass salesforce mass email limits and at the same time let you send simple marketing emails to Schedule one-off mass emails.

Check out the following link:
[MassMailer App Link on AppExchange](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000005uxj5EAA)

Comment: Hi, Your answer, as much as it may answer the O needs, is still an advertisement to your own product. Add notice on that in your post. And don't hide behind anonymous accounts please.

Comment: I wanted to give the right solution to the readers.Salesforce have a limitations of sending mass emails to externel emails id.So there is a solution MassMailer. we have integrated an app sendgrid with salesforce to send mass email using Lead,contact.